# Excel VBA - Using Application Input Box To Get A Users Selection Of Cells - Is It Possible To Get Users Worksheet Details?

Tags: excel, vba, user-input

I am trying to do some coding using Excel VBA. (I am very new to coding VBA with Excel.)

What I want to do is to get the user's selection of cells from an Application.InputBox. My issue is the user will be selecting cells that will be located in another open worksheet. I know I can get the details of the user's selection by using the .Address property. The problem is, this only returns the cell range and omits the details of the file and worksheet. My question is, is it possible to gain details of the user's file and sheet. Surely, this must be possible because it is visible in the inputbox when the user is selecting their cells?

Thank you very much for taking the time to make any comments(!)

My code used so far is shown below:

```
Sub UserSelectsCells()

Dim rng As Variant

On Error Resume Next
  Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
    Title:="Select Test Cells", _
    Prompt:="Please Select The Cells Which Test Whether The User Has Answered The Questions Correctly", _
    Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

'Test to ensure User Did not cancel
  If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

MsgBox rng.Address
Range("M10").Value = rng.Address

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rng.Parent` to get the worksheet.

See

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.parent

You can use `.Parent` on the worksheet to get the workbook.

See

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.parent

Also check out:
[Get Workbook Name and Worksheet Name from a Range in Excel-VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51018904/get-workbook-name-and-worksheet-name-from-a-range-in-excel-vba)

Comment: To add to the list: One can also use [`Range.Worksheet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.worksheet).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ed2 - you were very helpful. I made much progress after your help so I am very grateful that you took the time to post.

Yes - I found that to get the name of the workbook you use rng.Parent.Parent.Name and to get the name of the worksheet you use rng.Parent.Name